# PHP Split array of objects into multiple arrays by key=>value

Tags: php, arrays, object

I would like to split an array of objects into multiple arrays by key=>value, but I couldn't figure it out how.

I have an array like this:

```
Array => (
 [0]=>stdClass Object(
  [id]=>1
  [title]=> Title1
  [content]=>Content1
  [cat]=>Cat1
  [date]=>20140910
 )
 [1]=>stdClass Object(
  [id]=>2
  [title]=> Title2
  [content]=>Content2
  [cat]=>Cat2
  [date]=>20140910
 )
 [2]=>stdClass Object(
  [id]=>3
  [title]=> Title3
  [content]=>Content3
  [cat]=>Cat1
  [date]=>20140910
 )
)
```

and I would like to split this by "cat"=>"value" and create an array like this

```
Array => (
 [Cat1] => Array(
  [0] => Array(
   [id]=>1
   [title]=> Title1
   [content]=>Content1
   [cat]=>Cat1
   [date]=>20140910
  )
  [1] => Array(
   [id]=>3
   [title]=> Title3
   [content]=>Content3
   [cat]=>Cat3
   [date]=>20140910
  )
 )
 [Cat2] => Array(
  [0] => Array(
   [id]=>2
   [title]=> Title2
   [content]=>Content2
   [cat]=>Cat2
   [date]=>20140910
  )
 )
)
```

So this is what I'm trying to do but I couldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `casting`. Use `(array)` before object. An example here..

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($obj as $val){
    $newArr[$val->cat][] = (array)$val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worekd! I didn't thought that the solution would be so simple. I tend to over think things :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array();
foreach ($objects as $k => $v) {
 if (!isset($array[$v->cat])) {
   $array[$v->cat] = array();
 } 
 $array[$v->cat][] = (array) $v;
}
```

Comment: No need for `!isset($array[$v->cat]) ..`, just `$array[$v->cat][] = ..` will do just fine.